# For loop that goes back and forth

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

For loops that counts forward and backwards is very trivial, but if I want it to goes forward and then backwards I can do 2 loops.

Then I had this idea to do it in a single for loop, it works but I don't like how it looks, does anyone have a more elegant way

```
var array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];

for(var x=0,i=0; i<(array.length*2)-1; ++i, x = (i>=array.length)?(array.length-2-(i%array.length)):i){
    printf(array[x]);
}
```

`x` goes min..max..min

http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/48sJg/2/

Comment: Just use several loops and extract the loop body into a method. Don't try to be overly clever, it simply makes the code hard to read and hard to maintain. Anyone wanting to understand this – including you in a month – will have trouble deciphering what this does.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/48sJg/4/

Comment: @adeneo you should make your comment an answer

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing it out there, if backwards-then-forwards (max-min-max) works for you, you can do this:

```
var array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
for (var c=-(array.length),l=array.length;c<l;c++) {
  console.log(array[Math.abs(c)]);   
}
```

output:

```
F
E
D
C
B
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing yourself or anyone else reading this code any favors making things overly complicated. Code should be readable and maintainable. My recommended approach (which models similar behavior to `Array.prototype.forEach`, but without modifying the prototype) is

```
Array.cycleThrough = function (arr, func, scope) {
    'use strict';
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(i in arr) {
            func.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
        }
    }

    for(i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(i in arr) {
            func.call(scope, arr[i], i, arr);
        }
    }
};

var foo = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
Array.cycleThrough(foo, function (current, index, array) {
    console.log(current);
});
```

Though the name `cycleThrough` certainly can be improved, too. The structure was taken from [MDN: Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to be as consistent with ECMAScript as possible.

The callback function will, as you can see, be called with the current element of the iteration, the index it is at and the entire array itself. You can also pass a custom scope on which the callback should be called on.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to mirror and concatenate the array.

```
var array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
var reversed = array.slice().reverse(); //["F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
var mirrored = array.concat(reversed); //["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
```

Then just do a regular loop to iterate.

Comment: +1 for being the easiest to understand, though it technically does not achieve the same output as the OP's code: based on OP code, "F" should only be output once in the middle. Though, this could be an oversight on the OP's end!

Comment: It's nice and simple, but it does unnecessary concatenation of an array to itself just for the sake of iteration.

Comment: the array was just a visual thing, the main point was a general purpose loop/iterator

Comment: If you don't want to hit the last item twice, you can add arguments to the slice method

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track of the direction of the loop:

```
var array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];

for (var i = 0, dir = 1; i > -1; i += dir, dir *= i == array.length - 1 ? -1 : 1) {
  console.log(i, array[i]);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Mv36H/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a "direction" variable.  When you reach the end of the array, invert the direction...and for the condition, just make sure you're not before the beginning of the array (which you won't be unless the previous iteration is part of the return trip and just processed element 0).

```
for (var i = 0, di = 1; i >= 0; i += di) {
    if (i == array.length) { di = -1; continue; }

    /* do your thing with array[i] */
}
```

This will visit the last element twice.  If you only want to visit it once, then have the statement say

```
    if (i == array.length - 1) { di = -1; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a_different_name/AM4q7/1/)