# C# loop going back and forth

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I'd like to make a for loop that goes backwards after it reaches the end.
So when "i" reaches 10, instead of "i++" it should do "i--".

I've looked online for a little bit and couldn't find anything in C#. There's [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034365/for-loop-that-goes-back-and-forth), yet it's in JavaScript. I've rarely coded in JavaScript before, so I'm not sure how to translate that code into C# (if that even is possible).

I've successfully achieved this using the code below, yet it's lacking in the "readability" department. It also requires an extra variable, which I don't think is the most elegant solution.
Here's the code that I've written:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool reverse = false;

            for(int i = 0; i <= 10;)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                if(i == 10) reverse = true;
                if(i == 0) reverse = false;
                if(reverse == false) i++;
                if(reverse == true) i--;
                
                // Slow down the output
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

        }
```

Again, this code works fine, yet I'm looking for a better solution than this mess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You created an endless loop. Is this really what you want. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not go for a while loop and iterate i manually?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why on Earth would you not solve this problem by writing two loops, one after the other?

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, an endless loop is what I'm trying to achieve, but instead of resetting when reaching 10, I would like it to count backwards until it reaches 0, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As small readability improvement I would suggest to change from the boolean flag to an integer increment value:

```
        int increment = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i >= 0 && i <= 10; i += increment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            if (i == 10) increment = -1;
            else if (i == 0) increment = 1;
        }
```